# Big O time complexity for two inserts in an array in a loop?

Tags: big-o

Each insert to a python list is 0(n), so for the below snippet of code is the worst case time-complexity O(n+ 2k) or O(nk)? Where k is the elements, we move during the insert.

```
   def bfs_binary_tree(root):
     queue=[root]
     result=[]
     while queue:
          node = queue.pop()
          result.append(node.val)
          if node.left :
            queue.insert(0, node.left) 
          if node.right:
            queue.insert(0, node.right)
      return result
```

I am using arrays as FIFO queue, but inserting each element at the start of the list has O(k) complexity, so trying to figure out the total complexity for n elements in the queue.

Comment: Hello eukaryota! I updated the question with the actual python code.  Does it make it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each node ends up in the queue at most once, the outer `loop` will execute `n` times (where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree).

Two inserts are performed during each iteration of the loop and these inserts will require `size_of_queue + 1` steps.

So we have `n` steps and `size_of_queue` steps as the two variables of interest.

The question is: the size of the queue changes, so what is the overall runtime complexity?

Well, the size of the queue will continuously grow until it is full of leaf nodes, which is the upper bound of the size of the queue. Since the number of leaf nodes is the upper bound of the queue, we know that the queue will never be larger than that.

Therefore, we know that the algorithm will never take *more than* `n * leaf nodes` steps. This is our upper bound.

---

So let's find out what the relationship between `n` and `leaf_nodes` is.

**Note: I am assuming a balanced complete binary tree**

The number of nodes at any level of a balanced binary tree with a height of at least 1 (the root node) is: `2^level`. The max level of a tree is called its `depth`.

For example, a tree with a root and two children has 2 levels (0 and 1) and therefore has a depth of 1 and a height of 2.

Thhe total number of nodes in a tree `(2^(depth+1))-1` (-1 because level 0 only has one node).

`n=2^(depth+1)-1`

We can also use this relationship to identify the depth of the balanced binary tree, given the total number of nodes:

If `n=2^(depth+1) - 1`

`n + 1 = 2^(depth+1)`

`log(n+1) = depth+1` = number of levels, including the root. Subtract 1 to get the `depth` (ie., the max level) (in a balanced tree with 4 levels, level 3 is the max level because root is level 0).

**What do we have so far**
`number_of_nodes = 2^(depth+1) - 1`
`depth = log(number_of_nodes)`
`number_of_nodes_at_level_k = 2^k`

**What we need**
A way to derive the number of **leaf nodes**.

Since the `depth == last_level` and since the `number_of_nodes_at_level_k = 2^k`, it follows that the number of nodes at the last level (the leaf nodes) = `2^depth`

So: `leaf_nodes = 2^depth`

Your runtime complexity is `n * leaf_nodes` = `n * 2^depth` = `n * 2^(log n)` = `n * n` = `n^2`.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation.